# Call converted input from another cls.cs file

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio, web-applications

I have a aspx, aspx.cs and cls.cs file.

cls.cs file :

```
  public void convertphone(string phone,out DataTable dt)
        {
            string strSql;


            strSql = " select convert || substr('" + phone + "', 22, 11) ";
           strSql +=   " AS Converted from phoneconvert ";
            strSql +=  " where phone_partno = substr('" + phone + "', 1, 15) ";



            cls.GetDataTable(strSql, out dt);



        }
```

My aspx.cs file

```
protected void InvisButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string phone = Scancuba.Text;
    resultscan.Text = "";

    //bool result = Cls.convertphone(phone);

Cls.convertphone(phone,out dt);


    if(result==true)
    {
        resultscan.Text = "Insert success " + phone;
        resultscan.Style.Add("background-color", "#90ee90");        
    }
}
```

My problem is, when I insert an input, the query works and convert my input into the format that I want but in the display message, it display " Insert success (the original input that has not convert yet)".
I know that it because I didn't pass the converted value, but I don't know how to code that.
I'm extremely noob in asp.net but please guide me.. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Most importantly, if my phone number is `1123',1,1)OR [something evil here];-- comment`, do I win free access to your database? (and why do you create the variable p and then assign it the value of the variable phone?)

Answer (score 1):

It's because your **Phonecheck()** method doesn't actually "convert" anything. All it does is look to see if the item exists in the database and returns **true** or **false**. To use the value it retrieved from the database, you'd need to change it something like this:

```
public string Phonecheck(ref string phone)
{
    bool success = false;
    DataTable dt = new DataTable();

    string strSql = "SELECT phone_partno ";
    strSql += "from phoneconvertcode  ";
    strSql += "WHERE phone_partno = substr('" + phone + "', 1, 15) ";

    cls.GetDataTable(strSql, out dt);

    if (dt.Rows.Count == 1)
    {
        success = true;
        phone = dt.Rows[0][0];  // assign "converted" value to phone ref parameter
    }

    return success;
}
```

To understand this, you need to understand how a `ref` parameter works. Basically, it means you can reset the value that the parameter contains within the method, and this value will be "remembered". https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/ref